# Select2 multiple values doubles prepopulated values on init, and still sends

Tags: jquery-select2

There are a lot of questions about select2 doubling values, and many of them don't have accepted answers.

On the surface everything looks fine but when I delete a token it's still sending it in params.

Checking the values of the `input` (which `select2` is hiding)

Prior to initializing `select2`

```
$('#language_list').val() //=> "english spanish italian"
```

After init

```
$('#language_list').val() //=> "english spanish italian,english,spanish,italian"

// It's clearer what's going on like this.
// And I don't know if it's significant but tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
$("#user_language_list").select2("val") //=> ["english spanish italian", "english", "spanish", "italian"]
```

Lots of issues are coming up like when the form repopulates after an error I'll have

```
$('#language_list').val() //=> "english-spanish-italian english spanish italian,english,spanish,italian"
```

Hidden in my `input` which I have to address on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked was cleaning the value before sending your data to the `callback`

You'll probably recognize this as basically the code from the docs.

```
    initSelection: function (e, callback) {
      var tags = e.val().split(/, |,| /);

      for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i].trim();
        tags[i] = {id: tag, text: tag};
      }

      callback(tags);
    }
```

But you just need to clean the val

```
    initSelection: function (e, callback) {
      var tags = e.val().split(/, |,| /);
      e.val("")
      for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i].trim();
        tags[i] = {id: tag, text: tag};
      }

      callback(tags);
    }
```